# Adding document(s) to draft envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Does anyone have any success adding documents to a draft envelope following the examples in the REST API?

1. Add Documents to a Draft Envelope - I can't get this to work at all.
2. Add a Document to a Draft Envelope - I have partial success. On the web console, I can see the document is added to the envelope, but when trying to open the document, the document shows "Unable to load PDF". The link to the document looks like `https://demo.docusign.net/Member/noname.pdf?d=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&...`

The PUT request that I used for #2:

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"SendOnBehalfOf": "xxx", "Username":"xxx","Password":"xxx","IntegratorKey":"xxx"}
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="api_upload.pdf"; documentId=3; fileExtension="pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

[base64 encoded bytes removed]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: So what error message(s) are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and was able to add two documents to a draft envelope with the following PHP code.  If you enter your credentials this code will Login, Create a Draft Envelope, then add 2 documents to that draft envelope, all in one go.

To run this code just:

1. Save file locally.
2. Enter credentials at top.
3. Copy two pdfs to same directory, name them document1.pdf and document2.pdf.
4. Run the code.

Note:  The REST API documentation for this call has some inaccuracies, the below request body works so follow this instead...

```
<?php

// Input your info here:
$integratorKey = '...';
$email = '...';
$password = '...';
$name = 'John Doe';

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create a draft envelope
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array (
    "emailBlurb" => "This comes from PHP",
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API Testing",
    "status" => "created");   
$data_string = json_encode($data);  

// *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    return;
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
echo "Document is created! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n"; 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 3 - Add documents to draft envelope
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array (
    "documents" => array( 
        array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => "document1.pdf", "order" => "1" ),
        array( "documentId" => "2", "name" => "document2.pdf", "order" => "2" )
    ));  
$data_string = json_encode($data);  

$file_contents1 = file_get_contents("document1.pdf");
$file_contents2 = file_get_contents("document2.pdf");

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data_string\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"document1.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents1\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"document2.pdf\"; documentid=2 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents2\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

// *** append "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents" to baseUrl and as endpoint
$url = $baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/documents";
$curl = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n"; 
?>
```

One last thing I'll note, is make sure you are doing a PUT request for this call and not a POST, as that's a common mistake I see here.